# Determinar ordem de exibição de consultas ordenadas no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, order-by, order

Tenho três tipos de ordens na tabela e preciso obter o resultado de forma que eu escolha quem indexará primeiro.

Preciso a respetiva ordem de indexação: ( ***ORDEM_COMUM EM PRIMEIRO*** )

`ordem_comum`, `ordem_lancamento`, `ordem_catalogo`

Tentei os exemplos abaixo ambos trazem a `ordem_lancamento` primeiro

```
EXEMPLO 1:
        .
        .
        .
         ORDER BY ordem_comum, ordem_proposta, ordem_lancamento";


EXEMPLO 2:
        .
        .
        .
        ORDER BY ordem_comum ASC, ordem_proposta ASC, ordem_lancamento ASC";

 EXEMPLO 3:
        .
        .
        .
        ORDER BY ordem_lancamento, ordem_proposta, ordem_comum";
```

CÓDIGO COMPLETO DA SELEÇÃO ABAIXO.

(*Não foi eu que modelei e nem tenho permissão de alteração portanto evitar comentários desnecessários*)

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM  `IMAGEMCONTROLE`
INNER JOIN  `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA` ON  `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA`.`PRODUTO_PROPOSTA` = `IMAGEMCONTROLE`.`IMAGEMCONTROLE_PRODUTO`
WHERE `IMAGEMCONTROLE`.`IMAGEMCONTROLE_LINHA` >0
ORDER BY `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA`.`ORDEM_LANCAMENTO_ESPECIAL`,`PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA`.`ORDEM_PROPOSTA`,`PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA`.`ORDEM_LANCAMENTO`, `IMAGEMCONTROLE`.`IMAGEMCONTROLE_CATEGORIA`";
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente o seguinte:

```sql
SELECT
    ordem_comum,
    ordem_proposta,
    ordem_lancamento
FROM
    tableName
ORDER BY
    ordem_comum ASC,
    ordem_proposta ASC,
    ordem_lancamento ASC
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Da uma olhada no código completo da seleção, tentei colocar  'campos,*' mas não da certo